# Update <span> content from external source with jQuery in WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create a live updating data from an external source inside WP.

I have tried to use wp_enqueue_scripts to include the script on my page. It actually appears there but is not updating the `<span>` I want to update.

Here is the code have.

**In Functions I have**

```
function my_stats() {   
    if( is_page(7680) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-file', 'https://domain/stats.js');
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_stats' );
```

Then the **stats.js** contains the following simple script

```
$(document).ready(function refreshStats(){
    $("#stats").load("https://domain/stats.php");
    setTimeout(refreshStats, 50000);
});
```

I have also tried making the function in stats.js starts with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function refreshStats() {
```

But it sill the same result.

Also, I didn't forget to put the **HTML** code on the page

```
<div id="stats">Loading</div>
```

If I use this code outside WP it works, but in WP it just shows the Loading text from the `<span>`
If I search in the source for `stats.js` I can see it.

I have tried to search for some information, but everything points me to the scenario above.
I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the version of jQuery that WP comes with. Somehow it did not want to work with my script. I have tried using that version in the standalone instance of the script and it failed as well. So that's how I concluded that it must be the jquery version.

So, just to avoid dependencies, I took a different approach, which worked.

**Here is the code I used.**

```
$(document).ready(function refreshStats(){
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/stats.php');
        client.onreadystatechange = function() {
          document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = client.responseText;
        }
    client.send();
        setTimeout(refreshStats, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'jquery' as a dependency of your script (see [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)).

```php
function my_stats() {   
  if ( is_page( 7680 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'js-file',
      'https://domain/stats.js',
      array( 'jquery' ) // <-- jquery as a dependency
    );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_stats' );
```

Also, try replacing both occurrences of `$` with `jQuery`, like so:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function refreshStats(){
    jQuery("#stats").load("https://domain/stats.php");
    setTimeout(refreshStats, 50000);
});
```

A bit off-topic: You might also want to look into [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried all sorts of tricks..  array( 'jquery' ), jQuery in front of #stats. Nothing worked. It turned out that somehow the WP version of jQuery does not want to work with my script. Truly odd behavior. I decided to go with a simple JS to overcome dependency. I will post my solution later.

Comment: @lStoilov Oh, I see. I've read before about people having issues with the WordPress version of jQuery. I'm glad you figured it out. Happy coding :)